# google_mobile_ads: Failed to load a banner ad in production on real device

Tags: flutter, admob, google-mobile-ads, firebase-admob

The app I use shows `google_mobile_ads` on a test device but shows no ads on a real device.
Moreover, it shows this in logs on real device

> I/flutter (14971): Failed to load a banner ad: No ad config.

I found some person said that *you must publish the application on the store and then download it on your device, and the ads will appear*.

Is it true? Is the app must be published before the ads will be shown?

p.s. when using `firebase_admob` I facing the same issue - on a real device in prod it shows no ads but works with test device, so maybe the issue lays somewhere deeper?

Comment: check app readiness status https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10564477

Comment: @AmodGokhale accordiding to the above link, the app which is unpublished is unreviewed and so it cann't recive ads, but I gues how my unpublished app which is using firebase_admob still shows ads?

Comment: @rozerror - you can get test ads for unpublished app on test device. It should pass all app readiness checklist before live ads are displayed for new app.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to upload to the store, you can add test device from Admob panel or use test ids to view ads, please review the
[document.](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/quick-start)

Comment: my test device works fine and shows ads. the issue with real (another) device.

Comment: Okey add test device to admob panel and you can test on real device.

Comment: well, I do not need test it on real device. I need the app to show real ads on real device.

Comment: Yeah i think you must publish the application on the store.